# Is there anyway to disable network connections on 3G for some application?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, cellular-data

I want some applications connect to Internet only when wifi connection is available. How can I do that?

Comment: That's not possible, at least at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't**, at least at user level.

The App's Developer can, of course, detect if the device is connected either by WiFi or 3G, and act accordingly.